# How to deny the requests access on a site collection

Tags: powershell

SharePoint 2013,

In graphical mode, in the authorizations properties of a sites collection, we can decide if users can request the access or not.

I'm wondering how to do this in powershell.

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite http://URL
```

then

```
$spsite[dot]SOMETHING_I_CAN'T_FIND
```

I thought it was the way to do it, but no =/ And with my poor english, I don't find anything on google.

If it is more explicit with this :

1st, on the site collection, you do this
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC630042.png

Then you click on site authorizations, and you got this (can't post image without reputation :s )
http://hpics.li/4fbd8be

I just want to uncheck this parameter, in powershell :)

Regards,

Nico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `SPWeb.RequestAccessEnabled`, if set to false users can not request access to the web. But it seems to be only read only. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.requestaccessenabled%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

It seems to be related to `SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail`, so I would try setting this one to an empty string ("") and see how that works.

Zimmergren has written about it [here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/tip-requestaccessenabled-programatically-using-the-sharepoint-object-model), some useful comments

Comment: You just save me from a headache !

I confirm that SPWeb.RequestAccessEnabled is read only. But if i put the RequestAccessEmail to "" (empty). This becomes uncheck ! So users won't be able to request access  !

Thank you a lot @Robert Lindgren !